# Web keyboard input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a good way to implement user input in an html5 game using javascript.  I have put together this simple example of using keyup and keydown binds using jQuery:

```
function Keys() {
    var keys = {};
    this.keys = keys;
    $(document).keydown(
        function (event) {
            keys[event.which] = true;
        });

    $(document).keyup(
        function (event) {
            delete keys[event.which];
        });
}

var keys = new Keys();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jackgeek/ANZds/1/embedded/result/
(browse to the above and press a few keys at once)

If you try the example you can see that it only allows you to track a maximum of 5-6 keys at once and if you jam down a bunch of keys at once it doesn't respond.  This wouldn't be ideal in a video game!

Is there a more reliable/better way to track keypresses using html5 and javascript?

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery to the "Libraries" in jsfiddle.

Comment: In what kind of game do you need more than 4 keys at once?

Comment: in some cases its less keys than 4, try holding down A & D and then press either I or P.  You'll notice it doesn't register I or P at all (I tried this in chrome)

Comment: I think I may be encountering a hardware limitation with my keyboard rather than a software limitation...  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses